# Prevent to change some string from Google Closure Compiler?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Have this code:

```
var a = 'Start';
var b = ' here';
return (document.querySelectorAll + "").toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(a + b) == -1;
```

After Google Closure Compiler, this code will be:

```
return (document.querySelectorAll + "").toString().toLowerCase().indexOf('Start here') == -1;
```

**How to prevent changing this string because I don't need in parameter of indexOf 'Start here', very important that will be exactly 'a + b'? 
Do I have specific keys above this code that will explain GCC to not compile this code/string?**

Comment: If you want the paramter of indexOf to be the string `a + b` then why not use `'a + b'` instead of `a + b` in `indexOf` ?

Comment: Because I need that my code was not be parsed by some systems. They blocking my code with regex and I can't do anything

Comment: I need to change 'Start here' to 'Start' + ' here'. But compiler returning to me previous value @NickParsons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [experimental `@noinline` annotation](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler#noinline) which:

> Denotes a function or variable that should not be inlined by the optimizations.

To keep both `a` and `b` preserved, use:

```
function x() {
  /** @noinline */
  var a = 'Start';
  /** @noinline */
  var b = ' here';
  return (document.querySelectorAll + "").toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(a + b) == -1;
}
```

Result:

```
function x(){var a="Start",b=" here";return-1==(document.querySelectorAll+"").toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(a+b)};
```

[Demo](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520ADD%2520YOUR%2520CODE%2520HERE%250Afunction%2520x()%2520%257B%250A%252F**%2520%2540noinline%2520*%252F%250Avar%2520a%2520%253D%2520'Start'%253B%250A%2520%2520%252F**%2520%2540noinline%2520*%252F%250Avar%2520b%2520%253D%2520'%2520here'%253B%250Areturn%2520(document.querySelectorAll%2520%252B%2520%2522%2522).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(a%2520%252B%2520b)%2520%253D%253D%2520-1%253B%250A%257D)

(Note that since `document.querySelectorAll + ""` evaluates to a string already, you don't need to call `toString` on it again - you can leave that part off if you want)